# Windows Server 2003: How to save everything in drive D?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a client who has 5 computers and 1 Windows Server 2003. The client saves all the files from the program to drive D (285GB) in the server which is a network/shared folder. In drive C: which is 12GB always seems to be out of space/full even though other computers are saving everything through D:.

I looked into the server's PC and saw that in drive C saves all the Windows log, temp, and administrator documents (confirming by looking at the date/time). Nobody uses the administrator documents in any of the 5 computers.

When drive C gets full, the users in other 5 computers are unable to save anything (even though directly through drive D).

I would like to know how to keep the drive C from getting low in available space and save everything in D including temp/windows log/document and few other things thats related to the system.

Comment: Get a bigger hard drive.

Comment: So the 5 PCs are saving their data to Drive D: which is a network drive? Is it the clients or the server that is filling up?

Comment: @vcsjones getting a bigger hard drive is not an option since I only want to work with the problem what the client currently have at the moment

Comment: @Kirk yes the server has drive C and drive D and all other client's 5 pc saves their file in the drive D which is the network drive. The server drive C is the one filling up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a Dell server? I inherited a crap ton of older Dell servers with a 12 G C: partition. Here is what i did:

- Start by making sure you have a good backup.
- Defrag each drive using a quality defrag utility (such as Diskkeepper)
- Download gparted, and repartition the drives as follows. I, for my own sanity, would perform and apply each action one at a time, rebooting between each action.

  - Shrink D: to free up space for C:
  - move D: all the way to the right.
  - if D: is in an extended partition, then move the beginning of that to the beginning of D:
  - extend C: into the free space.

There will be some chkdsk activity, which is normal.

Comment: yes its actually Dell. I was looking into and decided not to format/partition and deleted mostly temp folders and few useless files in drive C to free up the space. it may be a hassle but less hassle to redo the whole 5 pcs to link to that server again. i do noticed that every files/program is saved in drive D but in drive C saves all the profile info of each users who log in the server using desktop remote connection. what is recommended to delete in drive c without affecting the system.

Comment: Ok. I would like to point out that repartitioning wouldn't affect any of the functionality of the server (the clients would not have to be touched.) In my experience, it is only a matter of time before your server crashes, because it is next to impossible to control what is stored on C:. Microsoft updates that are downloaded in the background will fill your drive before you know it. I finally broke down and decided to repartition when Microsoft filled the C: drives on 2 domain controllers in a single weekend.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get a bigger hard drive, partition D: and make one of its partitions the new C:, copying the existing C: onto it and recycling that sad 12gb drive. Make sure you create a backup of D: before you re-partition it though!

Barring this, I doubt there's any way to move everything to the other drive, although you might think about moving the swap file to another drive as per [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307886), which should also work on Server 2003 (which is basically XP AFAIK).

Comment: @btown so first I would save everything in Drive D to the external harddrive as backup. and format D? the shared drive is drive D and it would be a hassle to have all the 5 pc(all diff. location) to save everything to drive C. Im still wondering how can Drive C be piling up when no one is touching it at all? everytime someone saves a file in drive D it seems something else also saves in drive C im looking for solution to avoid that. =)